# Problems with binding in DataTemplate

Tags: silverlight

Im having some problems with databinding inside a DataTemplate. In the ControlTemplate below the textbox in the Grid works and prints out the correct value. But the TextBlock inside the HyperlinkButtons DataTemplate does not work. Though the HyperlinkButtons NavigateUri is bound correctly. Could anyone plz help me with this

I have created a simple example that illustrates my problem.

MainPage.xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="SilverlightApplication8.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="400">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="EventControlTemplate" TargetType="Button">
            <Grid>
                <!--WORKS-->
                <!--<Grid >
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TitleTextBlock" Text="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Red" FontWeight="Bold" />
                </Grid>-->

                <!--DOES NOT WORK-->
                <HyperlinkButton TargetName="_blank" NavigateUri="{Binding Url}"                                  >
                    <HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding Title}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
                </HyperlinkButton>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">

        <ItemsControl x:Name="Links" Foreground="White" >
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border >
                        <Button Template="{StaticResource EventControlTemplate}" Click="Button_Click"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace SilverlightApplication8
{
    public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<Events> events = new List<Events>();
            events.Add(new Events(){Title = "This is title 1", Url = "http://www.thesun.co.uk"});
            events.Add(new Events(){Title = "This is title 2", Url = "http://www.thesun.co.uk"});
            events.Add(new Events() { Title = "This is title 3", Url = "http://www.thesun.co.uk" });

            Links.ItemsSource = events;
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Events
    {
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please take a few minutes to read the FAQ and the Markdown documentation (a useful synposis of which is available in the right hand margin when editing a question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `ContentTemplate`, the `DataContext` of which will be the `Content` of the `HyperlinkButton`. Since you haven't set the `Content`, you're attempting to bind against `null`.

This should work:

```
<HyperlinkButton TargetName="_blank" NavigateUri="{Binding Url}" Content="{Binding Title}">
    <HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Foreground="Green" Text="{Binding .}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </HyperlinkButton.ContentTemplate>
</HyperlinkButton>
```

But then that begs the question as to why you're even setting the `ContentTemplate` instead of just doing this:

```
<HyperlinkButton TargetName="_blank" NavigateUri="{Binding Url}" Content="{Binding Title}"/>
```

Comment: I simplifyed the example. But I have multiple bindings inside the Grid.

Comment: But I just modified Content="{Binding}" and inside the DataTemplate I could add many textblocks inside the grid :) Amazing. Thanks alot!!!